# Excel VBA Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a ComboBox in a userform, and I'm looking for a method to use to find what the selection is so that I can utilize that as a string and pass it to a cell on the sheet. For instance:

```
 Private Sub Filter_Click()
 'The Userform is called Summary, and the ComboBox in question is named Month_Filter
 If Summary.Month_Filter = "January" Then .......
 Call UpdatedTotals
 End Sub


 Sub UpdatedTotals()
 Dim ChosenDate as String
 If Summary.Month_Filter <> "" Then ChosenDate = Summary.Month_Filter.Value
 Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ChosenDate
 End Sub
```

Comment: ComboBox has a `.Value` property that should work, unless it's a multi-column combobox.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the combobox is accessible using:

```
Me.comboBoxName.Value
```

So something like:

```
If Me.comboBoxName.Value = "January" Then ....
```

would work.

However, this only applies to code written in the form's code (if that makes sense).  You won't be able to use that code in a separate module as it won't know anything about Me.comboBoxName...  If you want to use that value in a different module you would have to pass the value when calling that sub/function.

Comment: *would have to pass the value when calling that sub/function* -- not ncessarily. In many cases it's possible to refer to the form & control by name, e.g., `strVar = UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value`.

Comment: what does "Me" refer to?

Answer (score 1):

The `Value` property will return the value of the `BoundColumn` for the selected list item.

The `ListIndex` property returns the index (starting at zero for the first item) of the selected list item.  It can be used with `Column` to get the right value if the value you're looking for is not in `BoundColumn`.

```
ChosenDate = Summary.Month_Filter.Column(Summary.Month_Filter.ListIndex,1)
```

The second argument, 1, refers to the second column as it's zero-based just like the list items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Filter_Click()
 If Summary.Month_Filter.Value = "January" Then .......
 Call UpdatedTotals
 End Sub


 Sub UpdatedTotals()
 If Summary.Month_Filter.Value <> "" Then Range("A1").Value = Summary.Month_Filter.Value
 End Sub
```